# Get request within page

Tags: html, get, request

I've been looking around, but I'm not quite sure what to search for...

I want to have a webpage send a Get request to a python script when you first open the page, maybe with the option to refresh it with a button. Is there a way to send a request ("script.py?var=test") and display the results within the page?

What I tried to use earlier: (didn't work..)
Am I doing something stupid? I don't know anything about JavaScript

```
    <p>Highscores:</p> 
    <p id='scores'>text</p> 
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "../../cgi-bin/highScore.py?scoreMethod=load&game=ulama", true)
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        var done = 4, ok = 200;
        if (request.readyState == done && requeset.status == ok){
                document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    };
    request.send();
}
</script>
```

Also, should I have the python script return a full page with the header and all? or just the relevant section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Jquery call in this case to clean up your code a little bit.

Also in this case you should use a post because of the nature of your 'beast' :)

```
function changeText(){
$.ajax({
 method  : "POST",
 URL     : "../../cgi-bin/highScore.py",
 data    :  {   
                "scoreMethod" : "load",
                "game"        :  "ulama"
            },
 success  :  function(data) {
       $("#scores").html(data);
 }
});


}
```

I'd also look into JSON and jquery being returned as its probaly going to be easier in the long term (Though ive never played with python.

Answer (score 0):

why not using jquery for doing this?

```
$('#scores').load('../../cgi-bin/highScore.py?scoreMethod=load&game=ulama', function(responseText, textStatus) {
      alert(textStatus);//check here whether textStatus equals 'success' or something else (maybe an error)
});
```